# Python: When using venv, how do I include a package I installed outside of the venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have a few Python packages that I use for every project (Black, PyLint), and I want to have these packages in every `venv` I create, so I don't have to manually install them each time.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's posibble to set PYTHONPATH in each venv and have those packages installed once. Although I would try to not do so. Maybe only for cases with really big AI libs

Comment: it's better to use a requirement.txt file and define package there, and install from them, instead of depending on system dependency and in case of difference version of python then it will make issue